# Change the SAPI Microsoft Speech Object Library Voice with Delphi code

Tags: windows, delphi, text-to-speech, sapi

I'm using the 'Microsoft Speech Object Library' and I would like to change the default voice through delphi code.

My default voice is a woman speaking. How do I change it to someone else if someone else is available?

I'm using SAPI 5.4 and Delphi XE6.

Comment: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee125652.aspx read the documentation and work with the examples

Answer (score 3):

You did not say which version of SAPI you are using, or show the code you are using to invoke SAPI with.

For instance, in SAPI 5, the [`ISpVoice`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms719576.aspx) interface has a [`SetVoice()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms719807.aspx) method, where you pass it a [`ISpObjectToken`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms718134.aspx) interface for a specific voice.  To get the `ISpObjectToken`, you can:

1. use [`SpEnumTokens()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms717535.aspx) to enumerate available voices until you find one you want.
2. use [`SpFindBestToken()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms717543.aspx) to find a voice that matches various criteria you specify.
3. use [`SpCreateNewToken()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms717514.aspx) or related function if you know the specific voice you want to use.

Comment: I'm using SAPI 5.4 and I haven't written any code yet, because I do not know how to use those code you gave above. I currently only know how to let it speak the text. Using the SPVoice1.speak()

Comment: `SPVoice1.Speak()` is code, so obviously you have "written any code". You would simply call `SPVoice1.SetVoice()` before calling `SPVoice1.Speak()`. You need to learn how to use the functions I mentioned so you can obtain a token for different voices. If you do not call `SPVoice1.SetVoice()`, `SPVoice1.Speak()` uses whatever default voice is configured in the Windows Control Panel.